# Can't see IAM user instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

1. I had a client get an AWS account.
2. I then had them create an IAM user account for me with admin privileges.
3. I made an EC2 instance under my IAM account.
4. They can't see the EC2 instance in their account.

How do I make it so they can access the instances I make given that it's really all under their account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There few things you can check.  The client should be in the same region of the instances that you are creating.  If you created instances in N. Virginia and when they are logged in to the console and it shows US. West they won't see the instances.  The second thing just to make sure is that the account their are using is admin and/or they have `AmazonEC2FullAccess` role attached.